# Regex expression to take text in double quotations except when ending with specifc word

Tags: python, regex

So I'm attempting to grab text from a file when it appears in double quotations, EXCEPT when the text within the quotations ends in a certain suffix.

For example below, I'd want everything NOT ending in VER that is in quotations to be parsed.

Example Input:

```
"GameVER": ["GM435615-IQR", "LG-QR435", "HG145-IR9", "WUT828-PQR10"] "VERIZON": ["GKSL42375834-45", "DG-67498", "GF4564", "HFJ-88.8.98"]
```

Output:

```
GM435615-IQR
LG-QR435
HG145-IR9WUT828-PQR10
VERIZON
GKSL42375834-45
DG-67498
GF4564
HFJ-88.8.98
```

In python, I've tried this:

```
re.findall(r'(\"\b.+?)(?!VER)\b\"',text)
```

But it still grabs the words with VER on the end.

Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: Holy cow, these are already lists and dictionaries, why in the world would you want to do regex over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `VER` is being caught in the `.+?` (the `?` makes the `.+` non-greedy but in this case the only way for a `....VER` to be caught is by having it in the `.+?`). Instead of saying "match stuff not followed by 'VER'", try "match a word where the last 3 characters are not VER" (i.e. an end quote not *preceded* by 'VER').

Also, instead of using `.+` try `[^"]` which will avoid your `.+` matching across multiple words.

```
re.findall(r'\"(\b[^"]+)(?<!VER)\b\"',text)
```

example:

```
>>> text='"GameVER": ["GM435615-IQR", "LG-QR435", "HG145-IR9", "WUT828-PQR10"] "VERIZON": ["GKSL42375834-45", "DG-67498", "GF4564", "HFJ-88.8.98"]'
>>> re.findall(r'\"(\b[^"]+)(?<!VER)\b\"',text)
['GM435615-IQR', 'LG-QR435', 'HG145-IR9', 'WUT828-PQR10', 'VERIZON', 'GKSL42375834-45', 'DG-67498', 'GF4564', 'HFJ-88.8.98']
```

(by the way in your output above you missed out "HG145-IR9" and "WUT828-PQR10" although they do not end in VER and are in double quotes?)

Comment: Thanks works great! And yes I forgot to include those last two items in my output.

Question though: What exactly does [^"] do?

Comment: It means "Match anything that isn't a quote mark". You know how `[a-z]` matches all letters from a-z and so on? Putting a `^` in like `[^a-z]` means "match everything *except* what I've specified in the `[]`".

Answer (score 1):

1. Step 1.  Add commas.

   ```
   with_commas = "],".join(text.split("]"))
   ```
2. Step 2.  Create dictionary.

   ```
   my_dict = eval("{%(text)s}" % {"text": with_commas})
   ```
3. ???

   ```
   results = [item for sublist in my_dict.values() for item in sublist]
   for item in my_dict.keys():
       if item[-3:].lower() != "ver":
           results.append(item)
   ```
4. Profit.

   ```
   print results
   ```